# Do ubuntu 23.04 has a LTS version? If it has, how to upgrade from 22.02 LTS to 23.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade

There is no sign of LTS version of 23.04. so do we have to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 23.04 ... If I want only the LTS version?

Answer (score 6):

LTS (Long Term Support) releases occur every 2 years, in April. Each LTS release is supported by the community for five years (not one year). There are additional non-community support options after five years.

The most recent LTS release was 22.04 in April 2022.

The next LTS release will be 24.04 in April 2024.

- See https://ubuntu.com/blog/what-is-an-ubuntu-lts-release for the explanation of what an LTS release is, and how it's different from the Interim (formerly "Standard") 6-month releases of Ubuntu.
- See https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle for the explanations of when LTS releases occur.